# Best practise for using session variables with forms to create model instances

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework, playframework-2.2

Say I have a model FsqCheckIn:

```scala
 case class FsqCheckIn( userId: Int, restaurantId: Int, date: Date, rating: Int )

 val myForm = Form( mapping( .... )  )( <Special apply function> )
```

And a form that a user can fill to check in. My question is,

1) Should I make userId an input of type hidden and then use value from there? Or,

1.1) Add a field 'user' to the Form[T] instance but don't show this to user. Add my own bindFromRequest that will populat this with the current logged in user.

2) Make userId a var in the case class, and then change it's value to the logged in user's id after the form binding succeeds? Or,

3) Is there a way for me to override `bindFromRequest` such that I can access request directly? Or,

4) Is there a way for me to access request inside my `special apply function` so that I can extract the logged in user id and stamp it on the instance?

I apologize if the question is naive, but I'm very new to MVC and play framework.

Thanks!

EDIT: Added point 1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not expose anything related to user in a Form, unless you want to manage multiple users within same session. For a user-authnenticated view, you can always figure out which user is logged in. So change:

```
 case class FsqCheckIn( userId: Int, restaurantId: Int, date: Date, rating: Int )
 val myForm = Form( mapping( .... )  )( <Special apply function> )
```

To

```
 case class FsqCheckIn( restaurantId: Int, date: Date, rating: Int )
 case class FsqCheckInModel( userId: Int, restaurantId: Int, date: Date, rating: Int )

 val myForm = Form( mapping( "restuarantId" -> number,  "date" -> nonEmptyText, "rating" -> number) )( FsqCheckIn.apply)(FsqCheckIn.unappy _)
 val checkInData = myForm.bindFromRequest.get
 // handle validation and date conversion
 val user = getUserFromSession
 val cq = FsqCheckInModel(user.id, checkInData.restaurantId, checkInData.date, checkInData.rating)
 // save to db
```

Comment: This is close to a variation of (2) I mentioned. Thanks. I will mark this as answer if I don't get other replies. Although this (and my #2) seems 'kludgy' to me in that creation of two classes just for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

1: If you do, the user may change it, which, depending on your use case, might be dangerous

2, 3 & 4: You can create the format inside of your action and have access to the request. You could also build the Form inside a method that takes a request as a parameter if you want to use the same form in multiple actions,